# Dimensions are not showing in open cart website

Tags: opencart

My website is not showing dimensions i.e. length, height and width in product detail page.

I have added them though.
here is the link
[please click here](http://igloosales.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=33&product_id=30)

Answer (score 2):

This involves editing php files etc.

I can give you some hints

First in \catalog\controller\product\product.php

```
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
```

> $product_info['length'] , $product_info['height'] , $product_info['width']

Then you need to pass these values to the template file i.e

\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl

Answer (score 2):

you should check this link http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=16843#p179351

or

you could buy the extension special for this case : http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2937

[image: showing dimension of product in opencart]